# jQuery Mega Drop Down Menu Plugin

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using the jQuery Mega Drop Down Menu Plugin, one simple thing I can't get to work is I need the nav text to be centered in the menu. I removed all the "float:left;" delcarations but the nav text is still on the left hand side.

http://www.designchemical.com/lab/jquery-mega-drop-down-menu-plugin/getting-started/#comment-4334

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `text-align: center;`?

Text aligns to left by the default. All you need is this line.

Comment: Yeah I added that and it didn't change it.

Comment: margin:0 auto 0 auto; ?

Answer (score 0):

Could you paste you html code here?

One option could be Ignas said, if not there would be another CSS style aligning the text to the left.

I have reviewed the page you mentioned and the main items seems to be centered, not the sub-items.

If you want to center the sub-items , try this CSS rule:

```
.row li ul li a{
 text-align:center !important;
}
```

Comment: It wont let me post it too many characters. Here is a link to the examples.  http://www.designchemical.com/lab/jquery-mega-drop-down-menu-plugin/examples/